# really Strange thing with javascript time

Tags: javascript

Correct me if I'm wrong but until today I thought that:

```
var d = new Date();
var hour=d.getHours().toString()+":"+d.getMinutes().toString();
```

would return the user time depending on his location.

I live in Israel, and when I activate my US VPN service (NY), this code still returns the time in Israel.

- I deleted my all browser history and the problem still exists.
- I tried `www.uswebproxy.com` and the problem still exists.

You can see it for yourself here: http://davidnmd.com/timeproblem.htm

Comment: Javascript returns the time based on the system clock. It has no way to know where your VPN terminates - how could it change the clock?

Answer (score 3):

As JavaScript runs locally on your browser, your current system time will always be returned regardless of where the content is coming from.

For more details on the `Date` object in JavaScript, you can check out the [reference on W3Schools here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp).

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that because Javascript runs in the browser, it uses the system time. Try changing the time in your operating system and try again. It will most probably change your browsers time as well.

Answer (score 0):

This will return system's current time..

Comment: u can click on my link and tell me if u see your correct time ?

Comment: Yes i can see itd 15:00